# jQuery wrap without refresh

Tags: jquery, refresh

I need to wrap an iFrame in a div wihtout the iFrame reloading the content.  Is there a way to suppress the refresh or another way to wrap the content?

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: `$('iframe[src^="http://www.site.com"]').wrap('<div class="test" />');`

Comment: +1 very interesting, looks like a misbehaviour, only MSIE seems to do it like expected

Comment: any leads or workarounds to get it to not refresh?

Comment: This really needs to be solved - I'm having the same issue :)  My jQuery Tabs are causing an iframe to refresh every time you switch tabs due to this glitch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wrap` does a `wrapAll` function, in which jQuery clones the `<iframe/>`, and this causes the refresh in Firefox.

**update**: I think it is a bug with the iframe handling code in the browsers, because the following code is not working either:

```
var
  $i = $('iframe[src^="http://www.site.com"]'),
  $d = $('<div class="test"/>');

$d.append($i);
```

Comment: Tested this, the behaviour is related to DOM-methods like appendChild or replaceChild, not a jquery-issue.

Comment: this seems to send my js interpreter into a loop... did this work for you?

Comment: you're right. it is not working with my example either. it does not cause loop but reloads the iframe.

Comment: any ideas or work arounds to get it to not refresh?  Also, it only has to work in Firefox.