# Wrap content in a Div with javascript without iframe refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I want to wrap some content on my page in a div.

I can do this using the wrap function in jQuery but my issue is that I have a few iframes in my content which contain advertising and when you wrap the content it refreshes the iframes.

From what I can tell this is because behind the scenes it is cloning the content to be wrapped into the new div.

html

```
<div class="content">
   <iframe src="http://something.com/ads"></iframe>
</div>
```

js

`$(content).wrap('awesome_container');`

Ideally I would like to just slot in some open div tags before the content div and a few close div tags afterwards but I can't seem to add any divs to the page without it adding close tags.

Does anyone know of a way around this issue?

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate, although there's no accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397270/jquery-wrap-without-refresh

Also, this is a reported bug. Appears to be an issue with Firefox: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing the html or making a copy of it, see if you can get the desired result using jQuery's detach()
This will also allow whatever events you have associated with this element and its children to still function afterwards. It may be enough to preserve the iFrame object instead of killing it off.

```
var orphan = $(selector).detach()
someParent.html(orphan);
```

Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: That's really weird, it seems to work perfectly about 80% of the time and then I get a bit of weird behaviour the other 20% but that could be down to my page setup.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think `wrap` internally uses `html` method to set the markup into the passed in container because of which iframe is refreshed. If you use `append` method it will not refresh the `iframe` because it will just move element from one location to other. Try to create your awesome contianer and then append the `content` div inside this container.

```
$('.content').before("<div id='awesome_container' />");

$('#awesome_container').append($('.content'));
```

Comment: same issue with the append function